# Popen fails with No file descriptors available

Tags: c, popen

Why does the code below fail after a few seconds?

The error outputs No file descriptors available.

The code runs on a MIPS CPU.
I want to execute a shell command every second and get the result.

```
static char data[1024];

static void * my_thread(void * arg)
{
    while (true)
    {
        FILE * fp;
        fp = popen("ls /", "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: %s", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }

        while (fgets(data, sizeof(data) - 1, fp) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", data);
        }

        pclose(fp);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Linux kernel version: 4.14.81

EDIT: Maybe I have to mention that there is a `fork` after the thread is created.

Comment: All threads use the same `data` array without any protection, leading to *data races* and *undefined behavior*. Make the `data` array a normal local variable instead.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the size you pass to [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) includes the null-terminator. You don't need the `-1`.

Comment: And how many threads do you run simultaneously? What is the rest of your program doing? How many other files, pipes, sockets, etc. is the rest of your program creating?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No one is accessing `data` array but this thread only.

Comment: And is there only *one single thread*? You don't create any other treads using the `my_thread` function? Then there's even less reason for `data` to be global.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Rest of the program opens a TCP connection and creates a TCP listener. I'll try to to test in isolation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a `fork` in my main program that is called after the thread is created.

Comment: `fork` creates a brand new process that runs in total isolation from its parent process. What it does will not affect the parent process.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The problem most likely has to do with the code you didn't show.